# Wordpress options page and looping through callback functions

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, settings, admin

I'm creating a simple WordPress plugin which will set an Options page in the Settings menu where the client can add their business details.

I register all my fields with:

```
// Lets set an array for the inputs:
$fields = array (
  array( "name",           "Business Name:"),
  array( "tagline",        "Business Tagline:"),
  array( "logo",           "Business Logo:"),
  array( "owner_name",     "Owner's Name:"),
  array( "owner_title",    "Owner's Title"),
  array( "address",        "Address:"),
  array( "city",           "City:"),
  array( "province",       "Province:"),
  array( "country",        "Country:"),
  array( "phone",          "Phone:"),
  array( "secondary_phone","Secondary Phone:"),
  array( "fax",            "Fax:"),
  array( "toll_free",      "Toll Free:"),
  array( "email",          "Email:"),
  array( "website",        "Website:"),
);

foreach($fields as $field) {
  //id, title (label), callback, page, section(from add_settings_section), args
  add_settings_field("business_{$field[0]}", $field[1], "business_{$field[0]}_setting", __FILE__, 'main_section');
}
```

This simply loops through the settings in the array, adds all the fields I will need, and sets the references to the callback functions with `business_{$field[0]}_setting`.

I then have to create callback functions for each one like:

```
function business_name_setting() {
  $options = get_option('plugin_options');
  echo "<input name='plugin_options[business_name]' type='text' value='{$options['business_name']}' />";
}
```

I'm assuming there is a more graceful way to do this, as it would be incredibly redundant to individually create all the callbacks when they will essentially be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows:

The `add_settings_field` function takes a 6th parameter, which it passes to the callback function. I have sent it the value of `$field[0]`. I have also set the `add_settings_field` function to send all callbacks to a handler function now called `business_setting`.

The new foreach loop:

```
foreach($fields as $field) {
       //id, title (label), callback, page, section(from add_settings_section), args
       add_settings_field("business_{$field[0]}", $field[1], "business_setting", __FILE__, 'main_section', $field[0]);
   }
```

The new callback function, which is now passed our `$field[0]` value from earlier, can now use that key to create the correct inputs:

```
function business_setting($field) {
  $options = get_option('plugin_options'); 
  $full_field = 'business_'.$field;
  echo "<input name='plugin_options[{$full_field}]' type='text' value='" . $options[$full_field] . "' />";
}
```